# Create an arrow inside circled div using css

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have created a circled div using css and I would like to put an arrow facing towards right direction using css as well but I am stuck with it.

I have created a fiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/9scow7c3/2/

```
<div id="search">
    <input type="submit" class="circle-search-button" value="" />
</div>
```

I read somewhere that can be done using :after :before but I don't have that much amount of knowledge of css3.

If you can give me some hints then that would be great.

Comment: Yes inside the circle.

Comment: [Here](http://html-generator.weebly.com/css-shape-generator.html#007BFFy9z-69z-12z8z0) you can generate a css arrow, and then put it under one of the`:before/:after` tags, just add `content:'';` and `position:absolute;` and adjust the margins

Comment: You can't use a pseudo-element like `:after` on an input.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9scow7c3/5/ via http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the `:before` pseudo element:

- Change the `<input>` to `<button>` to allow child elements.
- The button is set as `position: relative` and the `position: absolute` pseudo element will position itself in relation to it
- The arrow is created from the top, left and bottom border. The transparent borders create a triangle shape

The pseudo `:before` element behaves the same as this:

```
<button>
    <div>I am :before</div>
</button>
```

CSS / HTML / Demo

```css
.circle {
  width: 15%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 15%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
}
.circle:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-top: solid 10px transparent;
  border-left: solid 10px #FFF;
  border-bottom: solid 10px transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -10px 0 0 -3px;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="circle" value=""></button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's all working now. Thanks once again for your help.